# How to prevent Xcode from making inconsequential changes to data model file

Tags: xcode, core-data, xcdatamodel

I'm working with Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255) on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I have the data model file (myproject.xcdatamodel/contents) in Git and that's great for tracking changes.

The problem I have is that whenever I inspect the data model in Xcode, to see names of entities and their properties, without me wanting to change any entity or property, Xcode makes minor changes to the contents file, such as putting items in a different order and changing the width, height, and X, Y position of some items.

That's a little frustrating since it is an ongoing nuisance to filter out these inconsequential changes. Is there a way to prevent Xcode from making any changes to the data model file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the grid editor style instead of the graph style.  That way you don't move the location of the boxes around and effect the file by accident.